# Codeigniter making <li> active on click (normal navigation behavioral expected)

Tags: css, codeigniter, navigation, uri

After a load of research (hours) both across here and the CI user guide I am at the end of my tether.

I have combined several answers to achieve what i want and it works as expected but does not set the `<li>` as active.

View

```
<ul class="nav">
              <?php
              $query = $this->db->query('SELECT menu_title, menu_url FROM menus');
               foreach($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
                <li <?php if ( $this->uri->uri_string() == $row['menu_url'] ): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?=$row['menu_url'] ?>"><?=$row['menu_title']?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>

            </ul>
```

this as it reads pulls from a table a set of navigation options and lays them out (works) but will not turn the css to active how ever I try.

Comment: As an aside: This is a poor use of CodeIgniter. Variables should be set in your controller using data retrieved in a model, then passed to the views. You are combining Model and Controller code all in your View. Refer to the documentation on for proper use of the MVC pattern in CI.

Comment: you are also missing a semi-colon on your `endforeach`

Comment: I do agree that this is a poor use of CI however, their are several instances of this being acceptable on Stack Exchange and was my assumption for achieving what I am after this was my only option (I am learning new things so I am open to suggestions). On the side everywhere else through out the application ad-hears to the MVC pattern.

Comment: what do you get in `$row['menu_url'] , since i think you are missing the `site_url()` here...

Comment: $row['menu_url'] = /home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be easy if you print both the variables in the if conition and check if the codition is true or not manaully..

i think in your case `/` is giving you trouble since ..`$this->uri->uri_string()` will return just `home` where as you have `/home` in your table..

try this

```
<?php if ( '/'.$this->uri->uri_string() == $row['menu_url'] ): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: and we have a winner, works a treat with my old view setup. Will this work with what ever i set in that row IE:/jobs/add or /home/about

Comment: yes it shouyld work.. you can try it out.. if not..the print it the uri_string()  and check it out and work like wise... let me know if any problem..

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to flesh this out for you:

**Model:**

```
class Menu_model extends CI_Model{
 public function get_title_and_url ()
 {
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT menu_title, menu_url FROM menus');
  return $query->result_array();
 }
}
```

**Controller:**

There are different ways that you can access this, but for now I just made the menu its own controller. Usually I would put menu logic into a class that extends CI_Controller so i could access it elsewhere

```
class Menu extends CI_Controller{
 public function __construct ()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('menu_model','menu');
 }
 public function index ()
 {
   $view['menu_items'] = $this->menu->get_title_and_url();
   $view['current'] = $this->uri->uri_string();
   $this->load->view('menu_view',$view);
 }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ul class='nav'>
 <?php foreach($menu_items as $m):?>
   <li <?php echo ($m['menu_url'] == $current ? "class='active'" : "");?>>
     <a href='<?php echo $m['menu_url'];?>'><?php echo $m['menu_title'];?></a>
   </li>
 <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

The way I would implement something like this would be to create a `MY_Controller` class to extend CI_Controller, and inside of it I would have this logic for creating the menu HTML, then pass it into a master page template for all pages using the menu. This way I would not have to repeat myself in every view and controller.

[This](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) is worth taking a look at. Phil Sturgeon has a great blog post about this type of thing.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion which i apreciate greatly however I have the same result as before, when i click on the link, it does not turn active.

Comment: does the uri_string match the menu_url that you are retrieving from the db?

Comment: I believe so, the URL from the database is /home, it works correctly onClick and we end up with example.com/home

Answer (score 0):

if your $row['menu_url'] is returning /home it won't match since the uri_string is going to return it without the /

Try this:

```
<?php
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT menu_title, menu_url FROM menus');
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
    $url = trim($row['menu_url'],"/");
    <li <?php if ( $this->uri->uri_string() == $url): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?=$row['menu_url'] ?>"><?=$row['menu_title']?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Personally I'd break it out and use a ternary if instead to make it cleaner but personal preference.

```
<?php
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT menu_title, menu_url FROM menus');        
    $uri = $this->uri->uri_string();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
    $url = trim($row['menu_url'],"/");
    <li <?php echo ($uri== $url) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?=$row['menu_url'] ?>"><?=$row['menu_title']?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: yeah I screwed up the order, the $url declare needs to go inside the foreach, will edit.